# Positioning with background-image complication

Tags: html, css

In this project I'm doing I'm having complications with the background-image for the container, causing there to be a line between the horizontal navigation and the header.

I'm inexperienced with positioning in CSS but maybe someone knows a way around this so it doesn't display like this and could save me some time next time around.

```css
/*
   New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
   Tutorial 4
   Case Problem 2

   Pizza Style Sheet
   Author:Sean Parsons 
   Date:1/25/2015   

   Filename:         pizza.css
   Supporting Files: 

*/

/* General Styling Rule */
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
header, aside, article, section, nav, header img {
display: block;
}
body {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}



/* Container Styling Rule */
#container {
width: 1000px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
background-image: url(redbar.png);
background-position: top left;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

/* Header Styling */
header img {
background-color: white;
height: 100px;
display: block;
}
/* Horizontal Nav Styling */
nav.horizontal{
height: 85px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
display: block;
background-color: white;
}

nav.horizontal li{
width: 160px;
float:left;
margin: 15px;
list-style: none;
line-height: 50px;
}
nav.horizontal li a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
background-color: red;
color: white;
border-radius: 30px 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px 25px;
}
nav.horizontal li a:hover{
background-color: rgb(255,101,101);
color: black;
}


/* Vertical Nav styling */
nav.vertical{
clear: left;
float: left;
width: 200px;
}
nav.vertical ul li{
list-style: none;
text-indent: 5px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
nav.vertical li a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
nav.vertical li a:hover{
color: black;
}
/* Main Section Styling */
#main{
background-color: rgb(255,211,211);
float: left;
width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
   <!--
      New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
      Tutorial 4
      Case Problem 2

      Red Ball Pizza
      Author:Sean Parsons 
      Date:1/25/2015   

      Filename:         redball.htm
      Supporting files: modernizr-1.5.js, notice.png, rblogo.png,
                        redbar.png, slice.png, toppings.png

      Pizza slice and toppings images from public domain site at:
      www.publicdomainpictures.net
   -->

      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Red Ball Pizza</title>
      <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
   <link href="pizzatxt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <header><img src="rblogo.png" alt="Red Ball Pizza" /></header>
   
         <nav class="horizontal">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>

         <nav class="vertical">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Salad</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Pasta</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sandwiches</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Pocket Pizzas</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Fish &amp; Shrimp</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Chicken &amp; Wings</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Beverages</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Dessert</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Download Menu</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Catering Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>

         <section id="main">
            <img src="toppings.png" alt="" />
            <p>At Red Ball Pizza, we want to satisfy every appetite. That's 
               why our menu contains a variety of different items. With 
               so many choices, everyone's favorites are available!
            </p>
            <p>
               Red Ball Pizza is NOT a franchise, a chain, or a corporation. 
               It is 100% locally owned and operated. Red Ball Pizza is 
               devoted to providing the highest quality and the best service 
               possible. Our only goal is to provide you with a great 
               pizza &#8230; EVERY TIME!
            </p>

            <div class="coupon">
               <h1>Classic Combo</h1>
               <p>16" 1-Topping Pizza
                  &amp; a 2-Liter of Your Choice
                  For Only $14.99
               </p>
               <p>Expires 3/14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="coupon">
               <h1>Pizza &amp; Stix</h1>
               <p>16" Specialty Pizza
                  Reg. Cheese Stix &amp; a 2-Liter
                  For Only $21.99
               </p>
               <p>Expires 3/14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="coupon">
               <h1>1/2 Price</h1>
               <p>Buy any 16" Specialty Pizza
                  at Reg. Price &amp; Get a 2nd
                  Pizza For Half Price
               </p>
               <p>Expires 3/14</p>
            </div>
            <div class="coupon">
               <h1>Pizza &amp; Wings</h1>
               <p>14" 2-Topping Pizza 
                  &amp; 12 Wings
                  For Only $15.99
               </p>
               <p>Expires 3/31</p>
            </div>
            <div class="coupon">
               <h1>$3.00 Off</h1>
               <p>Get $3.00 Off
                  any 16" Pizza at
                  Menu Price
               </p>
               <p>Expires 3/31</p>
            </div>
            <div class="coupon">
               <h1>Sub Dinner</h1>
               <p>1 Toasted Sub &amp; Chips
                  &amp; 1 20oz Soda
                  For Only $6.99
               </p>
               <p>Expires 3/31</p>
            </div>
         </section>

         <aside>
            <h1>Pizza Pizzazz</h1>
            <ul>
               <li>93% of Americans eat pizza at least once a month.</li>
               <li>Mozzarella was originally made from the milk of Indian 
                   water buffalo in the 7th century.</li>
               <li>75 acres of cheese is eaten every day.</li>
               <li>23 pounds of cheese is eaten every year by the average 
                   person.</li>
               <li>The tomato was brought back to Italy by Spaniards returning 
                   from Mexico in the 16th century.</li>
               <li>The busiest night for take-out pizza orders is                    Halloween.</li>
               <li>The first pizzeria opened in 1830 in Naples, Italy and is                    still operating today. We've been open since 1982 and 
                   we're happy to serve you today and tomorrow!</li>
            </ul>
         </aside>

         <footer>
            <address>
               Red Ball Pizza &bull;
               811 Beach Drive &bull;
               Ormond Beach, FL  32175 &bull;
               (386) 555 - 7499 
            </address>
         </footer>

      </div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing your `display:block`